# Python - Alternatives to df.iterrows() with better perfomance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have the following dataframe:

| Level2 | Level 3 | DateStart | DateEnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Monthly | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 |
| Monthly | 2 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 |
| Monthly | 5 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 |
| Semi-annual | H1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 |
| Semi-annual | H2 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 |
| Quarterly | Q1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 |
| Quarterly | Q3 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 |
| Quarterly | Q4 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 |

Initially all the 'DateStart' and 'DateEnd' datetimes are set to 2022-01-01 by default and I need to adjust them according to Level2 and Level3 Columns.
I can do this with df.iterrows() succesfully but it takes ages for the script to run as there are hundreds of thousands of rows.
This is my code:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
if df.loc[i, 'Level2'] == 'Monthly':
    df.loc[i, 'DateStart'] = df.loc[i, 'DateStart'] + relativedelta(months = int(df['Level3'][i]) - 1)
    df.loc[i, 'DateEnd'] = df.loc[i, 'DateStart'] + relativedelta(months = 1, days=-1)
elif df.loc[i, 'Level2'] == 'Quarterly':
    df.loc[i, 'DateStart'] = df.loc[i, 'DateStart'] + relativedelta(months = (int(df['Level3'][i][-1]) * 3) - 3)
    df.loc[i, 'DateEnd'] = df.loc[i, 'DateStart'] + relativedelta(months = 3, days=-1)
elif df.loc[i, 'Level2'] == 'Semi-annual':
    df.loc[i, 'DateStart'] = df.loc[i, 'DateStart'] + relativedelta(months = (int(df['Level3'][i][-1]) * 6) - 6)
    df.loc[i, 'DateEnd'] = df.loc[i, 'DateStart'] + relativedelta(months = 6, days=-1)
else:
    df.loc[i, 'DateEnd'] = df.loc[i, 'DateStart'] + relativedelta(years=1, days=-1)
```

This is what we need the outcome to be in this case:

| Level2 | Level 3 | DateStart | DateEnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Monthly | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-31 |
| Monthly | 2 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-28 |
| Monthly | 5 | 2022-05-01 | 2022-05-31 |
| Semi-annual | H1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-06-30 |
| Semi-annual | H2 | 2022-07-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| Quarterly | Q1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-03-31 |
| Quarterly | Q3 | 2022-07-01 | 2022-09-30 |
| Quarterly | Q4 | 2022-10-01 | 2022-12-31 |

Any help would be greatly appreciated to make this process faster

Comment: What all the possible values do you have in level2 ? Monthly, Semi-annual, Quarterly and ?

Comment: All dates should be in 2022?

Comment: There are several other possible values, but since only the ones mentioned will be used for the conditions above we can ignore other possible values. There are also other years other than 2022

Answer (score 0):

A few observations:

- The “Level2” column is redundant, since the values in “Level3” distinguish between the different period lengths.
- There are only 12+4+2=18 possible values for StartDate, and likewise for EndDate.

Therefore, it would be simplest to just precalculate all 18 possible values for StartDate and EndDate, and store them in a dict.

Then use:

```
df[“StartDate”] = df[“Level3”].map(start_dict)
df[“EndDate”] = df[“Level3”].map(end_dict)
```

—--

Edit: Although your question states that all dates are in 2022, your comment above indicates otherwise. In that case, you’ll need to construct a dict of deltas, rather than final dates. Then use map() as shown above, and finally add those deltas to the start date column.

Comment: Sorry I can’t type out a more complete answer right now. I typed that out on my phone. I think this gives you the gist of it, though. :-)

Comment: Could you code a sample with how the list of deltas should be when you have some spare time? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
start_date = {"Q1":"1","Q2":"4","Q3":"7","Q4":"10","H1":"1","H":"7"}
end_date = {"Q1":"3","Q2":"6","Q3":"9","Q4":"12","H1":"6","H":"12"}

df["DateStart"] = df["Level 3"]
df["DateStart"] = "2022-"+df["DateStart"].replace(start_date)
df["DateStart"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DateStart"], format='%Y-%m')

df["DateEnd"] = df["Level 3"]
df["DateEnd"] = "2022-"+df["DateEnd"].replace(end_date)
df["DateEnd"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DateEnd"], format='%Y-%m')+ pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)
```

You can replace "2022-"with your column year if you have one.
With this data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {
'Level2': ['Monthly', 'Quarterly', 'Monthly', 'Quarterly', 'Monthly', 'Monthly', 'Semi-annual', 'Semi-annual', 'Semi-annual'],
'Level 3': ['1', 'Q1', '1', 'Q4', '2', '2', 'H1', 'H1', 'H1'],
'DateStart': ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01'],
'DateEnd': ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-01', '2022-05-02', '2022-06-30']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**output**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use the groupby function of pandas and then the aggregation.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {
'Level2': ['Monthly', 'Monthly', 'Monthly', 'Monthly', 'Monthly', 'Monthly', 'Semi-annual', 'Semi-annual', 'Semi-annual'],
'Level 3': ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', 'H1', 'H1', 'H1'],
'DateStart': ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01'],
'DateEnd': ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-01', '2022-05-02', '2022-06-30']
}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_grouped = df.groupby(['Level2', 'Level 3'])
df_res = df_grouped.agg({'DateStart': np.min, 'DateEnd': np.max})
```

Comment: I don't think you understood my request, I can't just insert the dates in manually, I want to process the initial dates to be shown as the output according to Level2 and 3. I am not searching for a way to group them, but to process them faster